# Exercise 11.17 on John Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds [Proof verification]

Tags: solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

> Let $f(x,y) = x^2$ on $\Bbb R^2$ and let $X$ be the vector field $X = \text{grad}\ f = 2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Compute the coordinate expression for $X$ in polar coordinates (on some open subset on which they are defined) and show that it is not equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$.

Proof. Consider the smooth map (diffeormorphism in fact) $(x,y)\mapsto (\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\text{tan}^{-1}(y/x)) = (r,\theta)$. Then, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\text{tan}^{-1}(y/x)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$$
Now, as $x = r\text{cos}\theta$ and $y = r\text{sin}\theta$, the above can be written as $$\text{cos}\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-\frac{\text{sin}\theta}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$$
Hence, $$2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = 2r\text{cos}^2\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-2\text{cos}\theta\text{sin}\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$
But $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} = 2r\text{cos}^2\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-2r^2\text{cos}\theta\text{sin}\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$

Hence, they are different. Since I'm the beginner of this topic (book), I wonder if my proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.